# Unit Test with Asp.Net Web Api and customer filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, authorize-attribute

I am working on the Unit Testing in Asp.Net Mvc Web Api.
I have 2 projects

1: Catalog.Api - This contains all the controllers

2: Catalog.UnitTests - This contains the Unit Test for controllers

All Controllers are Inherit with "ApiController" and every controller has custom filter [AuthenticationFilter]. Here is my values controller.

```
    [AuthenticationFilter]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

And my custom is check the authorization token. Here it is

```
public class AuthenticationFilter: AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)

        {
            var request = actionContext.Request;
            var authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

            if (authorization == null || authorization.Scheme != "Bearer")
            { 
                ShowAuthenticationError(actionContext, "Authorization required");
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
            {
                ShowAuthenticationError(actionContext, "Missing Jwt Token");
                return;
            }

            var token = authorization.Parameter;

            var principal = AuthenticateToken(token);
            if (principal == null)
            { 
                ShowAuthenticationError(actionContext, "Invalid token");
                return;
            }
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
        private static void ShowAuthenticationError(HttpActionContext filterContext, string message)
        {
            var responseDTO = new ResponseDTO() { Code = 401, Message = message };
            filterContext.Response =
            filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, responseDTO);
        }
    }
    public class ResponseDTO
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in the Unit Test project i have a class and unit test method.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void CheckFilter()
        {
            try
            {
                var controller = new ValuesController();
                var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext();
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InVhbGkiLCJlbWFpbCI6InVhbGlAaW5yZWFjaGNlLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTU2NDY0NjIyMSwiZXhwI");

                controllerContext.Request = request;
                controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

                var result = controller.Get();
                Assert.IsTrue(result.Any());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
        }
```

I am calling my controller by adding reference of API project into my unit test project. So all controllers are available in the unit test project.

Issue is that when i call the values controller it always return the data. And when i remove the request and header so it is also returning the data but in that case that will be unauthorized.

I think my custom filter is not calling. How should that would be called and authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your question and configure that issue it is basically you are calling the controller directly.
Basically controller is a class and when you are calling that it is behaving like a simple class and call the method and send back the result. It is simple and clear

But in your situation you have project for your api so can do this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckFilter()
{
    try
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        // This is the resgister method which is written in you Api project. That code is after this method this method because i did the same thing to call my controller.
        Catalog.Api.WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        using (var server = new HttpServer(config))
        {
            var client = new HttpClient(server);

            string url = "http://localhost:PortNumberOfProject/api/values";

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            };
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Token");

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

Here is the WebApi Register method of Api project which is used to register the Api and Routes.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is your controller as it is. And now debug your test and add a break point in your [AuthenticationFilter] and OnAuthorization method.

```
[AuthenticationFilter]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: This means that you need to host the asp.net application in order to test it. Just doesn't seem like a good approach. You can only check for error codes. You can't mock a service and check it's values with this.